# Reset Button for a 'Click Counter' Android App

Tags: java, android

I am creating a small 'Click Counter' app, which basically has a button function, which when pressed, a textview field displays the number of clicks made.
I am trying to setup a 'Reset' button, which changes the value of the textview back to 0.  This is the code I have so far:

```
wreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wreset);       
wreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }
```

This changes the textview value to 0, however when the button is clicked again it starts back from the count which it was on when the reset button was clicked.
For example:
 a. the current count = 10
 b. reset button is selected
 c. current count = 0
 d. clicker button pressed
 e. current count = 11

Am I using the wrong statement or intent?

Comment: It sounds like you're not resetting whatever you're using to count the clicks. It's that you should be zeroing (and your display too depending on your implementation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your not resetting whatever counter you are using:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   yourCounter = 0;
   txtCount.setText("0");

}
```

Comment: Hey, you beat me to it. :-)

Comment: @Blundell when you say 'yourCounter' do you mean the name of the textView or the name of the java class?

Comment: or is it the name of the int?

Comment: @Mustafa the name of the int you are counting with

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the counter state in an instance field or a static field. Then set that field to zero on reset. For example:

```
private int counter = 0;

// ...

wreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wreset);
wreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        counter = 0;
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}

increment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increment);
increment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        counter++;
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int count = 0;
    count++;//increment the count
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counttxt);// resorce location
    text.setText("No.of Clicks " + count);// view in the text
```

Comment: Won't this always display 1? It's setting count to zero and then incrementing it once